# Cannot run login form with Shiro

Tags: java, security, jsf, shiro

I have searched many pages and follow, seem I'm not lucky guy, I cannot run my login page (I'm a newbie). When I clicked login button, nothing happen. Here is my web-app structure

login.xhtml (JSF form)

```
<h:form prependId="false">
        <h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGrid id="panel" columns="2" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
                <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Email" />
                <h:inputText id="username"  />

                <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password" />
                <h:inputText id="password" />

            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:commandButton value="Login" style="margin-top: 10px;"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
```

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<!-- Setup Apache Shiro for Authentication & Authorization -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

shiro.ini

```
[main]
authc = com.beacon.security.MetroFormAuthenticationFilter
authc.loginUrl = /login.xhtml
authc.successUrl  = /home

[urls]
/login.xhtml = authc
/errors/notAuthorized.xhtml = authc
/** = anon
```

Comment: can someone figure out my mistake !!!

Answer (score 1):

When you are using shiro, ShiroFilter should be the first filter in your filter chain

try changing your web.xml to

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<!-- Setup Apache Shiro for Authentication & Authorization -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```